# HTML video player IE / FF

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, video

How can you display a video (mpeg or avi) with controls (play, stop, fullscreen) in both internet explorer 7 and up and firefox 3.0 and up. **A lot** of the examples online only works for one of the other. And I can't seem to find one that does it all.

Constraints :

- I dont want a solution which needs me to export my videos to youtube or google video or others.
- I don't to convert the video to another format, such as flv or mov (avi and mpeg are widely used, there should be a solution where you don't need to convert them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this, however, you will probably have to convert your video files to .flv and use a free media player like the Longtail Player or the OS FLV player (Google them) to embed them on your webpage.

Alternatively, you can wait for HTML5 to come out; this will take a while for major browsers to accept but they have an easy `<video>` tag.

Comment: Edited : I don't want to change the format of the videos to flv (because of the time needed to convert every video, loss of quality, etc.)

Comment: HTML 5 doesn't allow script triggered fullscreen

Comment: It actually doesn't take that long to convert to flv, and it's something we ALL have to deal with. In fact, Youtube and all video playing websites out there all convert to FLV.